# Android accelerometer only moving to right and down (positive directions)

Tags: android, accelerometer

I just wrote some lines of code where I am trying to move a circle in the direction my accelerometer tilts to.

When i tilt to the right, the circle moves to the right.
When i tilt down, the circle moves down.

But now, when I want it to go up, it goes down instead, when I want it to go left, it goes right.

The cursor has two coordinates, x and y.
When it gets updated it calculates

```
x += mx;
y += my;
```

mx and my are from the onSensorChanged method.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    if(e.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gameView.setCursorX((int)Math.pow(e.values[1], 2));
        gameView.setCursorY((int)Math.pow(e.values[0], 2));
    }
}
```

Now my question is: How can i get negative movement? It seems like my onSensorChanged method only gathers positive directions?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every number gets positive when squared..

Comment: Saw that some minutes after posting this question, answered it by myself already :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, sorry for this dumb question... After looking after the issues I noticed, that I squared the results, what means there are only positive outcomes...

```
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    if(e.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gameView.setCursorX((int)e.values[1]);
        gameView.setCursorY((int)e.values[0]);
    }
}
```

That's my working code now... Sorry for any inconvenience!

Comment: Did you solve that? I mean get fired when the device is moving to down?